# Why are bash_completion scripts persistently in environment?

Tags: bash

I accidentally typed the command `export` into my console emulator (running Bash) instead of `export -p`, and now all the bash_completion scripts are persistently in my environment, even surviving reboot. I'd like to undo that but haven't been able to figure it out after some hours. I got as far as finding them in /etc/bash.bashrc but don't see what is sourcing that, and in any case still can't figure out how or why `export` with no args can do such damage.

This is under Knoppix, in the non-root `knoppix` account. When I `su -` the root account has no such problem.

[update: I don't know what I'm talking about. By "environment" I meant the output of the `set` Bash builtin, which was where the functions were showing. I should be using `env`. Anyway, what happened was that I have been using `set` in my Makefiles to test the generation of certain values, and I was surprised to suddenly see all those functions in the output. Then after reboot I checked from the command line and still saw them, not thinking to check from the Makefile (from which they no longer show, not being exported. So, problem solved; they were obviously in my `set` output all along, just hadn't noticed them before until accidentally typing `export` and seeing them in my `make set` output. Still it seems there's a mismatch in the documentation of bash to the behavior; `export` with no names is supposed to return a list of exported variables, not export everything.)]

Comment: Have you checked /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d ?

Comment: I had checked /etc/profile before; just checked /etc/profile.d/ and found bash_completion.sh, thanks! but stat shows it's been there all along, and `set` didn't show the scripts until after the `export`. weird.

Comment: You may want to add it as an answer to this post and accept it so that people know the question's dead.

Comment: What do you mean by “in my environment”? An environment doesn't contain scripts. Do you mean that the completion scripts are in your `PATH`? Or if you did mean environment variables, what variables are you talking about? Just what is the undesired behavior there: tell us a specific command, what it produces, and what it should do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all your variables with `env` and use `unset $VARIABLE` to remove all unnecessary variables from your environment and thus fix your problem.
You have to be careful to unset the right variables, because if you unset your PATH, for example, you won't be able to run any commands/applications.

While this doesn't explain what went wrong with your bash_completion scripts, it would undo the accidental `export`.

Comment: I did that before posting the question, but on reboot they were all back again.

Comment: since you're the only one who "answered" I'll give you the credit, especially since you reminded me about the use of `env` to show the true environment variables rather than using `set`. there's still so much about unix I'm really vague about :^\